# Use AMPscript to create dynamic math calculation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need help with developing some AMPscript to deliver dynamic math calculations in an automated email. The email will show the saving amount (compared with a bank) on an international money transfer.

The data points I have in my source DE are SellAmount, BuyAmount, BankRate. The calculation to determine saving is [SellAmount - (BuyAmount x BankRate) = Saving.

For example: 3,869 - (5,000 x 0.7435) = $151.50

Can someone help with the AMPscripting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole section in the [**official AMPScript documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm) for Math functions.

For your example, it'd be something like this:

```
%%[

var @sellAmount, @buyAmount, @bankRate, @saving

set @sellAmount = 3869
set @buyAmount = 5000
set @bankRate = 0.7435

set @saving = subtract(@sellAmount,multiply(@buyAmount,@bankRate))

]%%
```

**Output**

```
sellAmount: 3869 
buyAmount: 5000 
bankRate: 0.7435 
saving: 151.5
```